# Drop Down Menu hides permanently after am item is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my HTML

```
<div class="navigation navbar">
   <a href="https://freshfindsfarmersmarket.netlify.com/" class="example">Home</a>
   <a href="#" class="example">About</a>
   <a href="#form" class="example">Contact Us</a>
   <a href="#" class="example">Sign In <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
</div>
```

This is jquery

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".navigation");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".navigation a");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
});

$(".example").on("click", function() {
  $(".navbar").hide();
});
```

My **Drop Down Menu**  works fine, when it's clicked it shows all the links but when you click a link all the **Menu** hides and won't drop down again when it's clicked. The page has to be refreshed for it to work again.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Remove this part - $(".example").on("click", function() {
  $(".navbar").hide();
});

Comment: I tried it without that but the Menu doesn't hide when a link is clicked. I want it to hide when a link is clicked but also can be drop-down again if clicked. Any thoughts about how I can get that to work?

Comment: You can try: $(".example").on("click", function() { navLinks.classList.toggle("open");});

Comment: Did you try  $(".navbar").toggle();

Comment: Thank you so much  **Hanif**, it worked. I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours and it was that simple. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the menu hides after a menu link is clicked is this code:

```
(".example").on("click", function() { // When a element with "example" class is clicked
  $(".navbar").hide(); // Hide the menu
});
```

Just remove it.

---

You could also rewrite your code (more cleanly?) using jQuery: (Updated with calcification in comment.)

```
const $hamburger = $(".hamburger");
const $navLinks = $(".navigation");
const $links = $(".navigation a");

// Also could be $('.navigation, .navigation a').on(...)
$hamburger.add($links).on("click", () => {
  $navLinks.toggleClass("open");
});

// Remove to prevent undesired functionality (menu disappearing)
/*
$(".example").on("click", function() {
  $(".navbar").hide();
});
*/
```

Comment: But when I remove that it won't hide when a link is clicked.
I want it to hide when a link is clicked but also can be drop-down again if clicked.
Any thoughts about how I can get that to work?